# Why would a sprinkler increase water pressure to house?

Tags: water-pressure

Update:  Overnight, the pressure gauge spiked back up to 200.  I tried testing the sprinkler system again.  I ran the #7 valve (the one I noticed it was on when noise started happening) manually and nothing happened.  I took #7 out of the system control. Ran it and nothing happened as far as noise in the house but the gauge did show a spike to 160.  I added #7 back and when the system got to #7, the noise began, the red needle on the gauge dropped to 80 and the black needle went crazy between 35 and 45 psi.  Turning the sprinkler system off didn’t make a difference.  I turned main off and the noise stopped.  Turned main back on and the gauge is fine.  #7 is the same as the other valves. Do you think the pressure reducing valve is going out?  I don’t know what kind of pressure that sprinkler valve is adding that is different from any of the other ones.

Original Post:
Lately, there has been a loud noise in the house.  It seems to coincide when a particular sprinker valve starts running.  I cleared air out of the house pipes.  I added a pressure gauge to check whether the water pressure reducing valve is working properly.  It measured 50 psi.  Then I ran the sprinklers again and when the 7th sprinkler valve started (the same as before), the noise came back.  I turned off the sprinkler system and the noise was still going.  I checked the pressure gauge and the black needle was fluctuating and the red needle was at the highest position which is 200 psi.  I turned off the main water and the noise went away.  I turned on the main water and everything is fine.  Why would one sprinkler valve cause havoc and since it did, does this mean the water pressure reducing valve is bad?

Comment: I'd need to know a bit more about the connections, valves in the sprinkler and a few other things, but look into 'Water Hammer' that sounds like what is going on.  There are hammer arresters you can install.   This typically happens with Washers as its when the valve can open and close quickly. Depending on the sprinkler valve and what's on the back end of it (Drip, lawn, etc) the hammer could be worse.

Comment: Normally a load will reduce the pressure on the gauge. I wonder if that zone draws enough that the pressure reducing valve is at max flow and causing problems with the valve itself. I have not seen a water system that has more than 120 psi and most are below 90 in my area, seeing 200 would have me rebuilding or replacing that valve before all the faucets in the home are damaged at least cartridge type and washer-less types. You might try opening another water source to see if that changes the noise it may be at a “harmonic” and adding additional flow may eliminate it if it is water hammer.

Comment: I added an update to the top of the post.  Based on this should I change the pressure reducing valve?

Comment: I like where Ed Beal is going. Because the noise continues while the sprinkler zone runs, it seems like something must be fluttering in the (possibly) high flow rate. Some automatic sprinkler valves have a knob that can be dialed down to limit the flow. If yours does, try winding that down. It's interesting that manual control didn't trigger the noise, though -- could the sprinkler valve itself be oscillating on and off when operated by its electric solenoid? That together with high flow would make a water jack-hammer and would cause brief but large spikes in pressure.

Comment: Thank you, maybe switching out the sprinkler valve might work. Probably change the PRV also.